# Read ActiveDirectorySchema using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I am trying to read Active Directory schema data using `DirectorySearcher`, like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://********/CN=Schema,*****");

var filter = "(&(objectCategory=attributeSchema))";
var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry, filter);

var searchResult = directorySearcher.FindAll();
DirectoryEntry schemaTest2 = entry.SchemaEntry;

// error on this line: 
// "The directory cannot report the number of properties."
foreach (var prop in schemaTest2.Properties.PropertyNames) 
{
    string propName = prop.ToString();                    
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error happens? Or do you have any suggestion how to read AD schema using `DirectorySerarcher`?

Note: I can not use

```
ActiveDirectorySchema schema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();
```

as I am facing some other issue with that.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791(v=vs.90).aspx? Also, what are you trying to achieve, your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error here. 
The solution from Microsoft is below:

```
DirectoryEntry  myDirectoryEntry=new DirectoryEntry();
// Display the 'SchemaClassName'.
Console.WriteLine("Schema class name:" + myDirectoryEntry.SchemaClassName);

// Gets the SchemaEntry of the ADS object.
DirectoryEntry mySchemaEntry = myDirectoryEntry.SchemaEntry;

if (string.Compare(mySchemaEntry.Name, "container") == 0)
{
   foreach(DirectoryEntry myChildDirectoryEntry in myDirectoryEntry.Children)
      Console.WriteLine(myChildDirectoryEntry.Path);
}
```

In my case the container does not work `myDirectoryEntry.SchemaClassName = domainDNS` and to get some results I needed to modify the code into:

```
DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry();

    // Display the 'SchemaClassName'.
    Console.WriteLine("Schema class name:" + myDirectoryEntry.SchemaClassName);

    // Gets the SchemaEntry of the ADS object.
    DirectoryEntry mySchemaEntry = myDirectoryEntry.SchemaEntry;

    if (string.Compare(mySchemaEntry.Name, "domainDNS") == 0)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry myChildDirectoryEntry in myDirectoryEntry.Children)
            Console.WriteLine(myChildDirectoryEntry.Path);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

I hope it helps you.